# .NET Core - Simplest way to log in file

Tags: web-services, logging, asp.net-core-2.1

I saw a lot a topic about this but I can't find a simple answer. I want to write a web service running on Windows/Unix. This web service is written in .NET Core 2.1.

What is the simplest way to log in file using .NET Core ?

Something like :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyFunction")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostItem(int version)
{
    log.Info("Get Post for version " + version);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NLog is a flexible and free logging platform for various .NET platforms, including .NET standard. NLog makes it easy to write to several targets. (database, file, console) and change the logging configuration on-the-fly.](https://nlog-project.org/)

Supported platforms include .NET Core.

Comment: I tried and it seems to be very simple, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. The tutorial to use it is there : https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial